# C processes: fork() scope

Tags: c, process, scope, fork

I'm trying to understand exactly how to work with processes. More specifically what code is run, and what is not. I've written some example code to try and explain what i don't understand.

```
int main(){

  //Program code part 1

  int myfun(){
    if(fork()>0){

      //Program code part 2

    }
    return 0;
  }
  //Program code part 3

}
```

From what I understand, the parent process should execute code parts 1 and 3, and return 0 in myfun(). The child should execute part 2, definitely not 1. Will it then execute part 3? Since it's created in te scope of myfun() i would think not, but i'd really like to be sure before i make a mess of my program.

Comment: `myfun` is defined inside of `main`. I believe gcc has an extension to support this (it's not standard), but either way you are never calling that function.

Comment: You have defined `myfun` *inside* `main` - you can't do that in C.  Can you [edit] the question to clarifiy please.  Does `main` call `myfun`?

Comment: C doesn't allow nested function definitions.

Comment: Your code is invalid.  C does not permit you to nest the definition of one function (i.e. `myfun()`) inside the definition of another (`main()`).  With that being the case, all we can really say is you are mistaken: none of the code you present will even compile, much less run, without relying on extensions.

Comment: Wow!  That's four of us, all made the same comment in about a minute.

Comment: `fork()` clones the caller, then the child will execute part 3 if it is said so. The child exists in the middle of a run in the exact same state (at least roughly) of the caller (means with a given stack, variables, etc as if it had executed the code the caller did).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A successful `fork` returns twice–once in the parent with a `>0` pid, and once in the child with `0`. Both then continue from that point forward.

That's all there is to it, as far as control flow is concerned.

If your code is:

```
int myfun()
{
    if(fork()>0){
        //Program code part 2
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    //Program code part 1
    myfun();
    //Program code part 3
    return 0;

}
```

then the parent will run part 2 and both the parent and the child will run part 3 (unless the `fork()` call failed with -1, in which case there's no child).

If you want to limit the child, do `_exit(SomeExitCode)` where it should end.

( `_exit` is generally preferable over `exit` in forked processes, as the latter `fflush`es `stdio` streams
and calls `atexit` handlers and all this is likely to be undesirable in a child that has
its filedescriptors and process image duplicated from the parent.)